VS2022 ignores new component added into the project
Using VS2022 v 17.10.4 When I add a new component into the project , VS ignores its existence. I have to close VS, delete the obj and the bin folders, reopen VS, clear and rebuild the solution and it works for awhile until it happens again. In the picture below, it shows that it does not detect the error in the form. It compiles and run. Depending on what part of the project I am working on, it can take me a lot of time to figure that the problem is in this newly added form where the added context is being ignored by VS


Try cleaning the solution, then closing VS and deleting the cache at C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache.

Whether it is that the new component cannot be recognized in time, or the newly added code and form cannot be recognized. In both cases, you can try to clean up the VS cache as @mrSoh suggested: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<Version>\ComponentModelCache.
And restart VS to see if the problem still exists.

I deleted the cache and now it works perfectly. I tested with another new component and it also worked seamless

@BenJunior Sounds good, if you run into the same problem again, feel free to leave a comment here and let me know.

If you encounter the following situation: the newly added components cannot be recognized in time or the newly added code and forms cannot be recognized by the compiler in time. In similar situations, you can try to clean up the VS cache in the following location according to @mrSoh's suggestion: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ComponentModelCache, and then restart VS.
The reason for this is that when we operate on project files in VS (add, delete or modify), the IDE itself will maintain an internal cache to speed up file loading and project compilation, but sometimes this cache will be damaged or inconsistent, causing problems with the project.
